# Shell Script - How to run script after mysql is ready?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, mysql

I have a script (in a `.sh` file) to run once everytime i logged in. But I have to make sure that mysql service is already running before the main script in my `.sh` executed. 
Here is my draft:

```
function check_mysql(){
    // script for checking mysql
    return status
}
mysqlstatus = check_mysql()
while mysqlstatus == false {
    mysqlstatus = check_mysql()
}
// once mysqlstatus == true
// my main script
// my main script
// my main script
// my main script
```

How to write the above draft in shell script?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/mheadd/5571023

Comment: I need the script to run at the startup. So it must wait for mysql service. Good reference anyway ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found the answer! :D

```
while !(mysqladmin ping)
do
   sleep 3
   echo "waiting for mysql ..."
done
echo "starting the main script"
#main script
#main script
#main script
```

Comment: Be careful with many iterations on shell  loop. Se [this issue](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68236/avoiding-busy-waiting-in-bash-without-the-sleep-command).

Answer (score 3):

THANK YOU for bringing that mysqladmin ping command to my attention!

It's going to be a big help when dealing with Docker.

Here's what I ended up doing:

```
    # Returns true once mysql can connect.
    mysql_ready() {
        mysqladmin ping --host=database --user=root --password=MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD > /dev/null 2>&1
    }

    while !(mysql_ready)
    do
       sleep 3
       echo "waiting for mysql ..."
    done
```